# Generate register info and assembly code GCC - ARM

Tags: linux, gcc, arm

I am trying to fetch the register info for each of the `General purpose registers` in `ARM`.

For example, When we have a seg. fault, we create a core dump and from that we can examine, register info, for example: `info register r0` and the assembly code using `diassemble`.

I did try the following [link](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/v2faq/faq8_20.html)
This is the following error I get: `file format not recognized; treating as linker script`

Could it be that the way I am linking is wrong?

```
gcc -g -std=c99 -O2 -mthumb -S -march=armv7 -mthumb-interwork -static -ffunction-sections -O0 foo.c -c -o foo.o
gcc -g -std=c99 -mthumb -march=armv7 -mthumb-interwork -static -ffunction-sections -O0 foo.o -o foo
```

I saw one [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118097/gcc-arm-assembly-preprocessor-macro?rq=1) by `Nils Pipenbrinck`, but I did not understand how he fetched the register info.

Could you please tell me how do I get the register info?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: For example, in this link: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429137/how-to-print-register-values-in-gdb` , We saw how to get register info. but how do I get if I have no core dump.

This is what I get using the above technique: `gdb) info registers
The program has no registers now.`

Comment: If you don't have a core dump or some kind of tombstone I think you're going to have a hard time finding out the registers' values at the time of the crash.

Comment: The program won't crash, but is there a way for me to get the register info?

Comment: The ultimate issue is not related to the question.  `gdb` was not invoked correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiding my face in embarrassment: 
`gdb foo <pid>`

Comment: If the question was ultimately invalid, and the continued existence of it means nothing to no one, then please consider just deleting the entire thing.

Comment: OK. If the mods agree - I shall do that.