# How do I create #define macro with a ternary operator with one operand that does nothing?

Tags: c, macros

I am reading "No Bugs!" by David Thielen and chapter 3 discusses a way to determine if a given code path has been hit. It suggests having a macro that check an argument, and, if it is true, executes an assembly instruction that generates a specific interrupt (0x3) to create a debugger breakpoint. If the argument to the macro is false, it simply does nothing.

The macro, then, look like this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define Trap(t)     ( (t) ? __asm__("int $0x3") : )
#endif
```

This code, however, causes a compile error for gcc:

```
int_test.c:16:35: error: expected expression before ‘__asm__’
```

I learned from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6118305/3047531) that because gcc's asm is a block statement and not an expression, I must use [statement expressions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) in order to use the **asm** in this way. So, now it becomes:

```
#define Trap(t)     ( (t) ? ({ __asm__("int $0x3"); }) : )
```

The compiler still complains:

```
int_test.c:16:64: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
```

Okay, so now I have to do this?

```
#define Trap(t)     ( (t) ? ({ __asm__("int $0x3"); }) : ({ ; }) )
```

That seems really dumb. Can't I just have the preprocessor insert nothing if `t` is false without using this annoying syntax?

Note: I have left out a few other similar macros for simplicity and I have adapted the syntax from the book to work for gcc (such as replacing the book's _asm with **asm** as well as using AT&T syntax and surrounding the assmembly in "")

Comment: If you only need side effects and not values, why use the ternary operator instead of an if statement?

Comment: +1 to using `if` instead of ternary operator. **HOWEVER** I have to ask, why in the world are you using assembly instructions to trigger breakpoints instead of just using a real debugger and setting breakpoints at places of interest? This seems like a very, very primitive, unnecessary, low level and downright *ancient* debugging method...

Comment: Traditionally this is done through the comma operator. E.g. cond && (function_with_side_effects(), 1) though I'm not certain whether this will work for GCC inline assembly statements, so you may need to place the actual breakpoint in a separate function. Any particular reason you don't want to make the whole thing an (inline) function?

Comment: @David Norris: It is not an alternative to normal interactive breakpoints but rather a useful complement. They are typically used more-or-less as assertions except for conditions which aren't necessarily errors (to highlight rarely exercised code paths, say)

Comment: @DavidNorris If I just used the debugger, I would have to set the breakpoints by hand each time I run gdb, right? Unless there is a way to save a gdb config file or something. In either case, I'm just trying to learn from this book, but it was published in '92 so I guess it is dated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The advice you're getting from the book is essentially to create your own `assert()` functionality.

On most systems, you should just use the `assert()` macro that's provided in `assert.h`.  If the assertion is triggered and you're running under a debugger the assert will trigger a breakpoint (again - on most systems).

If for some reason you can't use the standard `assert.h` functionality (for example, maybe some sort of bare-bones embedded system toolchain that doesn't provide it), you can do something like the following:

```
#ifdef DEBUG_MODE
    void DoAssert(void);
    #define ASSERT(expr) ((expr) ? (void) 0 : DoAssert())
#else
    #define ASSERT(expr) ((void) 0)
#endif
```

And put whatever you need to have to trap into the debugger in the `DoAssert()` function - in your case that would be the inline assembly for `int 3`.

Comment: Ah, I see. This book was published in '92 so perhaps the assert() library was not introduced until after it was published.

Comment: assert() was certainly around at the time. The real difference is that this type of trap() is non-fatal. This way you can place a permanent breakpoint in a failure which your program knows how to handle (say a missing file) or some other edge case you'd like to know about

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using an instruction inside an expression anyway, use the conditional construct with instruction syntax instead of the conditional construct with expression syntax.

```
#define Trap(t)     ({ if (t) __asm__("int $0x3"); })
```

Alternatively, make it a function.

```
static inline void Trap(long t) {
    if (t) __asm__("int $0x3");
}
```

Though since you won't be using `Trap` as an expression much, given that it returns void (so you can only use it on the left-hand side of `,` or as a top-level expression), you might as well make the whole thing an instruction.

```
#define Trap(t)     do {if (t) __asm__("int $0x3");} while (0)
```